# Netbeans 7 / 7.1 javafx GUI designer / builder

Tags: netbeans, javafx, netbeans-7.1

is there any GUI builder available for JavaFX2 in Netbeans 7.0 / 7.1?
In previous Netbeans versions I've used the plugin "JavaFX Composer" but it seems to be that the plugin isn't avaialable for 7.0 and 7.1.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is one GUI tool: JavaFX Scene Builder.

You can download it from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html#sb

Go to downloads JavaFX Scene Builder.

There's also a tutorial on how to install it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/installation/jsbpub-installation.htm

Comment: Tutorial link dead.

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans 7.1 beta has the support for it as you can read here: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/

> Support for JavaFX 2.0

Comment: I agree with your statement. It supports fully JavaFX 2.0. But I can't find any informations about a GUI Builder for it....

Comment: I am using the OSX version of Netbeans 7.1 and I cannot find the JavaFX "gui builder"  I am pretty sure it's not available yet.  I hav looked quite a bit.

Comment: There is no GUI builder integrated in NetBeans, but you can use Scene Builder and then export your FXML file to netBeans JFX project

Answer (score 1):

No.

Or rather, not yet. The JavaFX Scene Builder is in the pipeline, see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2298158. I assume it will be integrated into Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

not now, 
seems that the scene builder will avaliable in the third quarter of 2012.

you can see the javafx roadmap.

http://javafx.com/roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

The official tool is [JavaFx Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) 
It creates FXML file with all the components 
You can ask queries and report problems in [Oracle Forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1385&start=0)

Answer (score 0):

When we right-click the *FXML file* in netbeans and choose *Open*, then NetBeans IDE automatically locates the latest installed *Scene Builder*.

if NetBeans cannot locate the installed Scene Builder :

1. From the Main menu, select *Tools* and choose *Options*.
2. In the *Options* window, click *Java* and then the *JavaFX* tab.
3. Specify the location of the *Scene Builder* installation folder and then click *OK*.